# Need to filter data based on column value in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I need to execute a query based on the column value database record. Here are some current values:

```
id    column_name
-------------------
5       30
6       39
2       10
1       38
9       54
3       37
```

If I pass the 39 and 54 it should display output like this:

```
id    column_name
-------------------
6       39
2       10
1       38
9       54
```

Query:

```
select CONVERT(column_name as CHAR(50)) as column_name from table name where CONVERT(column_name as CHAR(50)) >= 39 AND CONVERT(column_name as CHAR(50)) <=38
```

Comment: Why is 10 showing then? I don't understand what your attempting to get as results

Comment: On what basis you want to show record with column_name with 10

Comment: select CONVERT(column_name as CHAR(50)) as column_name
from table name where CONVERT(column_name as CHAR(50)) >= 39 AND CONVERT(column_name as CHAR(50)) <=38

Comment: Please don't use the comments for a running discussion. Edit your question with the additional information requested.

Comment: I just added it to the original post in an edit

Comment: aldrin has asked me for query so post it :) might be some can help

Comment: @YiiDeveloper, first, what SQL version and server are you working with? Second, are you wanting to make this a stored procedure?  Third, I haven't seen anything that makes this a PHP question.

Comment: @sadmicrowave maybe he's expecting the range of two dynamic data's.

Comment: @aldrin27, yea I misread the where clause.  Now my question is, with a WHERE clause like that, why wouldn't he want the other values that are `<= 38`, like 37 and 30?

Comment: @YiiDeveloper what is your sql?

Comment: @aldrin27 : right you got my point.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is right but some modifications are needed.

Use like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(`column_name`, CHAR(50)) as `column_name` from `table_name` WHERE CONVERT(`column_name`, CHAR(50)) >= 39 AND CONVERT(`column_name`, CHAR(50)) <=54;
```

For more visit: [SQL server convert()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) and [Mysql convert()](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/convert.php)

Comment: think you have it backwards.  He wants all values less than or equal to 38 and greater than or equal to 39, not between the two.

Comment: @ sadmicrowave you should refer the question.

Comment: yea, what am I missing? `>= 39` and `<= 38` ...?

Comment: well yea, thats my problem, his output doesn't match what he is attempting to do in the query.  His query illustrates him wanting something, while his output shows him wanting something else -- I'm not sure which is right.  Nonetheless, `BETWEEN` won't give him the result of `10` anyway, nor 38 and 39...

Comment: i don't want to filter BETWEEN value for numeric i have value with start column value and ending column value i need record b/w those two value

Answer (score 0):

No where clause logic could bring these lines based on the values 39 and 38.

If a SELECT would always bring these rows in that order than you could start thinking about using:

```
SELECT.... WHERE...   LIMIT x, 3...
```

Comment: or `SELECT TOP 3 ...` if `MS SQL SERVER`

Comment: True. Just assuming that it is a real case and somehow those lines could/should really coming up in that way...